# Connection Time out when accessing MWAA UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, mwaa

I created MWAA environment on the main default VPC where every service is running .I used the (private network) option to access the webserver. When accessing the airflow UI using my user the connection times-out and the site is not reached. The user have MWAA full access and access to the VPC

I added the MWAA ENVIROMENT to the main default VPC  to avoid two VPC pairing but I am afraid that's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

> I used the (private network) option to access the webserver.

You told MWAA to refuse connections coming from the Internet. You are now trying to connect to it from the Internet. MWAA ignores your connection attempt and never responds. Your browser waits and waits on the response, never gets one, eventually times out and shows you the error.

You need to set it to public network.